# Error while testing Wikixmlj

Tags: java

I want to extract the data from wikipedia page, so i'am using Wikixmlj API to access to wikipedia Dumps. The code of my test class:

```
package wikiXmlj;
import edu.jhu.nlp.wikipedia.*;
public class test {
public static void main(String args[]){
   WikiXMLParser wxsp = WikiXMLParserFactory.getSAXParser("D:\\simplewiki-20140501-pages-articles.xml.bz2");  
         try {
                wxsp.parse();
               WikiPageIterator it = wxsp.getIterator();
                  while(it.hasMorePages()) {
                   WikiPage page = it.nextPage();
                   System.out.println(page.getTitle());
                }       }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }}}
```

I am getting ttheis error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException 
at edu.jhu.nlp.wikipedia.WikiXMLSAXParser.getIterator(WikiXMLSAXParser.java:70)
at wikiXmlj.test.main(test.java:18)
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code .....

```
  public void wikiDumpReader(String dumpfile) {
            WikiXMLParser wxsp = WikiXMLParserFactory.getSAXParser(dumpfile);
            System.out.println("Going to process dump file");
            try {

                wxsp.setPageCallback(new PageCallbackHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(WikiPage page) {

                        System.out.println(page.getTitle());
                    }

                });

                wxsp.parse();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error :" + e);
            }
        }
```

This is working for me.Ref [https://code.google.com/p/wikixmlj/](http://ref%20link)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the iterator together with the SAXParser.

But the iterator only works with the DOMParser.

Switch

`WikiXMLParser wxsp = WikiXMLParserFactory.getSAXParser("D:\\simplewiki-20140501-pages-articles.xml.bz2");`

to

`WikiXMLParser wxsp = WikiXMLParserFactory.getDOMParser("D:\\simplewiki-20140501-pages-articles.xml.bz2");`

and it should work.